# Why is there always only the latest development milestone available for download?

Tags: development, downloads, iso

What's the reason why we cannot download `Ubuntu+1 Alpha 1` once `Ubuntu+1 Alpha 2` has been released?

It would be helpful to roughly find out when regressions started to show up (sometimes it's not as easy as simply downgrading one package).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CD images take up a *lot* of space. Consider all of the combinations of architectures and flavours that one might wish to download. I imagine that the potential use case for this (consider that this method of regression testing would only work for packages on the CD, which are likely to have lots of developer attention anyway) is sufficiently small that it is not deemed to be a worthwhile tradeoff.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the disk space argument seems flimsy. From current Alpha 1: alternate, desktop, server, DVD x 2 = ~13 GiB. x 5 milestones = 65 GiB - I'd even donate the hard drive! :P But sure, I know that's not the most missed thing in the Ubuntu world - just wanted to know if there's a special reason for not providing the older ISOs.

Comment: You forgot to do 65 x 3 (architectures), also it is likely to be server class storage, not something you can get for a few bucks.